# AWS Transcribe Saving to Folder in an Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting the following AmazonTranscribeService exception

**"The specified S3 bucket can't be accessed. Make sure you have write permission on the bucket and try your request again"**

Consider the following

```
var transcriptionJobRequest = new StartTranscriptionJobRequest()
                {
                    LanguageCode = targetLanguageCode,
                    Media = new Media()
                    {
                        MediaFileUri = "clients/project/fileName),
                    },
                    TranscriptionJobName = "myjob",
                    OutputBucketName = "clients"

                };
```

My access is for "clients/project" and not for "clients". Is that the cause of the permission issue. If so, is there a way I can set the output to be "clients/project"

Comment: sadly I'm also facing same issue today

Answer (score 0):

putObject access on clients/project/* or on clients/* should get you through from IAM role perspective

Comment: We can upload jpg and mp3 to "clients/project". Does that imply that we have putObject access. I suspect it's related to the transcribe service.

Comment: Initiator of the API need to have policy covering PutObject access. if in above 'we' probably using a different user/role which has putObject access. 

Probably in failed case you are hosting your application on some server and invoking transcriber API via SDK. Service role attached to the host need to have s3 PutObject included.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaFileUri` attribute should[0] have a value something like `s3://clients/project/fileName`

[0] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/APIReference/API_Media.html#transcribe-Type-Media-MediaFileUri